# Why image is not display on full screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display image on full screen  on `image click`. In other words o click of image it will show in full screen

I tried like this but not working

```
$(".imageBlock").click(function () {
    $('.imageBlock').css({'width':'100%','height':'100%','z-index':'9999'})
});
```

https://jsbin.com/hayalobixo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```
$(function() {

  var counter = 0;
  $('.currentPage').text(counter+1);
  $('#pre').prop('disabled', true);

  $('#next').click(function() {
    if (counter < 4) {
      counter++;
      $('.imageBlock').hide();
      $('.imageBlock').eq(counter).show();
    }
    $('.currentPage').text(counter+1);
  })
  $('#pre').click(function() {
    if (counter > 0) {
      counter--;
      $('.imageBlock').hide();
      $('.imageBlock').eq(counter).show();
    }
    $('.currentPage').text(counter+1);
  })

  $('#next, #pre').click(function() {
    if (counter == 0) {
      $('#pre').prop('disabled', true);
    } else if (counter == 4) {
      $('#next').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#pre').prop('disabled', false);
      $('#next').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  })

  $(".imageBlock").click(function () {
    $('.imageBlock').css({'width':'100%','height':'100%','z-index':'9999'})
});

})
```

Comment: set position absolute other wise it will take the height of container in which image is placed.  $('.imageBlock').css({'width':'100%','height':'100%','z-index':'9999','position':'absolute'});

Comment: **[Like this](https://jsbin.com/bupakoyuta/1/edit?html,css,js,output)**?

Comment: `no` https://jsbin.com/hayalobixo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: it show `1/5` ..full image in whole screen as a overlay..full screen and width

Comment: i cannot access  this link

Comment: as we show pop up screen ..!! on overlay same thing I need to show on image

Comment: https://jsbin.com/hayalobixo/1/edit?html,css,js,output ..see update

Comment: see this https://jsfiddle.net/snm3e8ob/

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
div.imageBlock.full{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".imageBlock").click(function () {
    $('.imageBlock').addClass("full");
});
```

Comment: but I think we need to increase image height and width

Comment: you better to use classes like this, rather than directly update css

Answer (score 0):

You can use - div as absolute positioned

```
$(function() {

  $(".imageBlock").click(function () {
    $(this).css({'width':'100%','height':'100%','z-index':'9999','position':'absolute'})
});
```

https://jsbin.com/kowogukave/edit?html,css,js,console,output